# Generalizing Arithmetic Operators

Tags: math, haskell, functional-programming, numbers

Multiplication of two numbers can be algorithmically defined like so: 'add the first number to itself a number of times equal to the value of the second number'. Exponentiation of two numbers can be algorithmically defined like so: 'multiply the first number by itself a number of times equal to the value of the second number'. Thinking about those definitions for multiplication and exponentiation raises a few questions...

Firstly, can a class of arithmetic operations be defined by starting with addition as the fundamental operation? I wrote up some haskell code to test that idea:

```
order1 x y = x + y
order2 x y = foldl (order1) x (replicate (y - 1) x)
order3 x y = foldl (order2) x (replicate (y - 1) x)
order4 x y = foldl (order3) x (replicate (y - 1) x)
order5 x y = foldl (order4) x (replicate (y - 1) x)
```

Sure enough, the meaning of 'order2' is multiplication and the meaning of 'order3' is exponentiation. The english language, as far as I know, lacks words for 'orderN' where N > 3. Does the mathematical community have anything interesting to say about these operations?

Also, given the recursive appearance of those 'order' functions, how might one write a function like this:

```
generalArithmetic :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
generalArithmetic n x y =   --Comment: what to put here?
```

that means multiplication when n equals 2, means exponentiation when n equals 3 ...?

Also, how might one generalize these arithmetic functions so that they could operate on all real numbers? The type of 'replicate' is, after all, Int -> a -> [a].

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: The general expression is [hyperoperation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation).

Comment: Multiplication/exponentiation of **natural** numbers can be defined as repeated applications of a "lower order" operation. It's harder to say what it means to interpret "x ^ -7.6" as "multiply x by itself -7.6 times".

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can start with peano arithmetic as the first order (increment)

[Brainf*ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) only has increment, decrement, and checks for non-zero value. Even with this it can do any computation any other computer program can do as long as it always has enough memory and you are not in a hurry to get the answer.

Such property is called [Turing completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) and `Brainf*ck` is such even without input and output. Thus with `<`, `>`, `+`, `-`, `[`,  and `]` you can make a program to solve all math problems solvable by other programming languages.

So far I have made programs that do addition, subtraction, averages, multiplication, division, modulus and square root with it.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody cares about a definition for what I earlier called 'generalArithmetic', here it is:

```
arithmetic n x y = if n == 0
                   then (x + y)
                   else foldl (arithmetic (n - 1)) x (replicate (y - 1) x)
```

Comment: If this were some real-world-thing and you'd care about efficiency at all, you'd also want to handle `n == 1` and `n == 2` as special cases and use builtin multiplication and exponentiation there.